# Declaration of ‘setxattr’ must be imported from module ‘Darwin.POSIX.sys.xattr’ before it is required

Tags: ios, objective-c, armv7, arm64

code is working fine on armv7 but compile for arm64 throws this "Declaration of ‘setxattr’ must be imported from module ‘Darwin.POSIX.sys.xattr’ before it is required" error.

```
u_int8_t b = 1;
    setxattr([path fileSystemRepresentation],
             "com.apple.MobileBackup", &b, 1, 0, 0);
```

any help plz?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution.
include `#include <sys/xattr.h>` in the class

Comment: In my case I had to #import <sys/utsname.h>