# Missing system headers (/usr/include) on macOS Catalina

Tags: xcode, header-files, macos-catalina

I just installed the macOS Catalina 10.15 GM.
Unfortunately none of my app frameworks compile. The system header files were not found.
On macOS Mojave there was a workaround, but it no longer works, the file won't be dowloaded (the workaround is explained [here](https://donatstudios.com/MojaveMissingHeaderFiles))

When typing `xcrun --show-sdk-path`, `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk` is printed on the Terminal. This folder also contains all the required headers. How can I tell Xcode to use those files?

This is how my module.modulemap looks like:

```
module PrivateNetwork [system]
{
    header "/usr/include/sys/socketvar.h"
    header "/usr/include/net/if_dl.h"
    header "/usr/include/net/if_types.h"
    header "/usr/include/net/if.h"
    header "/usr/include/netinet/in.h"
    header "/usr/include/netinet/tcp.h"

    header "/usr/include/netinet/tcp_var.h"
    header "/usr/include/netinet/tcpip.h"
    header "/usr/include/netinet/tcp_fsm.h"
    header "/usr/include/netinet/ip.h"
    header "/usr/include/netinet/ip6.h"

    export *
}
```

Error: `Header '/usr/include/sys/socketvar.h' not found`

Comment: What version of Xcode are you running?  Did you fire-up Xcode in order to install the system tools?  Did you update the Xcode command line tools?

Comment: Yes, I ran Xcode and I installed the CommandLineTools. Does anybody know where I can download the old 10.14 headers .pkg file?

Comment: Presumably you can see those socket header files in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Content/Developer/...` somewhere?  If so it might just be a case of modifying the paths in your `.modulemap`.

Comment: This works (I hope that there is some sort of environment variable) but now I get a bunch of other errors like /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/netinet/in_pcb.h:95:18: Definition of 'in_addr' must be imported from module 'Darwin.POSIX.netinet.in' before it is required.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with `.modulemap`s but it's something I will look into more now.  Looking at [related errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851876/declaration-of-setxattr-must-be-imported-from-module-darwin-posix-sys-xattr) it looks like it's just another header file required, but I am not sure.  I assume you are creating module maps for use with swift?

Comment: According to [this very old man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/inet_addr.3.html) `in_addr` is from `<arpa/inet.h>` so add that to your list.

Comment: I have added this include but it did not solve the error.

Comment: I just had the frustrating experience of discovering that the system tools must be reinstalled (by starting Xcode again and saying yes to the prompt) _after upgrading the operating system_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I simply added the full path to the modulemap. If there is a better approach, please let me know, but at least now the file compiles (I also had to reorder the entries):

```
module PrivateNetwork [system]
{
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/socketvar.h"

    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/netinet/ip.h"
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/netinet/ip6.h"

    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/netinet/tcp_fsm.h"
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/netinet/tcp_var.h"
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/netinet/tcpip.h"

    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/net/if_types.h"
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/net/if.h"
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/net/if_dl.h"

    export *
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could set the CPATH to the header directory.

```
export CPATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/"
```